# Changing the user when turning in my Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, login

On my macbook pro 2010 (running Yosemite 10.10.5) I have two users. My normal Admin account and a Guest account. Whenever my computer is turned off, it automatically logs into the guest account when I turn it back on. Can I change that so it logs into my normal Admin account whenever I turn on the computer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on High Sierra, so the wording might be a little different, but I don't recall this changing position recently:

System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options (bottom of the list of users) > Automatic Login (set to your user)

Comment: Additionally, you can disable automatic login from the Security preferences pane.